# How to use untwister?

Tags: c++

https://github.com/altf4/untwister

I wanted to use the above program to predict some PRNG. I have read the 'usage' part, I though I should use it in cmd.exe by entering the path of the untwister. I entered the path of main.cpp, only MSVC pops up. Also, MSVC doesn't allow me to debug/compile the file, so I cannot run it. I searched 'how to use untwister' on google, but there is no further instruction. I am a beginner of programming, please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: The simplest way to build probably would be install msys2 and use mingw to build using the Makefile: https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: @drescherjm I used mingw32-make, now I get the untwister.exe. But I still cannot use it. When I open it, an error message appear : _zst28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, based on @drescherjm comment's, I've successfully build it.

- I installed msys2 and use mingw to build it. But the .exe file has
  error "_zst28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv"
- I searched the error message on google, and discover that the problem
  may caused by gcc version.
- I downloaded an old version (10.3.0) of gcc and mingw here:
  https://winlibs.com/
- I typed "cd /d D:\abc" then "mingw64\bin\mingw32-make.exe" in cmd, it
  showed "Nothing to be done for" error.
- I discover that I can use option to force the mingw32-make.exe to
  read the Makefile. I added .am to the filename of Makefile, then type
  mingw64\bin\mingw32-make.exe -f D:\abc\untwister-master\Makefile.am
- The mingw32-make.exe thinks that files in
  D:\abc\untwister-master\prng are in D:\abc\prng, and tells me it
  can't find the files.
- I moved all files and folder to D:\abc, then success!